# Same request Parameters in Url String and POST request

Tags: html, jsp, httprequest

I have observed a confusing thing while checking some basics of query parameters and POST requests.
Below is a code portion in index.jsp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Index Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form name = "testForm" action="index.jsp?username=uname1" method = "POST">
        Username : <input type="text" name="username" value=""/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

<%
    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    out.println("Username = " + username);
%>

</body>
</html>
```

On running this code, When I enter the value in textbox username as 'uname2' and click Submit button, the output is shown as 'uname1'.

After that I change the method of form 'testForm' as 'GET' and then re-run the file on server.
When I enter the username as 'uname2' and click submit button, I get output as 'uname2'

I am not able to understand this behavior. Can anyone please help me understand why is this happening ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because multiple parameters with the same name can be submitted using GET, POST or by a combination of both. *The order in which they are applied is completely arbitrary*.

Look at the Servlet API  documentation and you will see the following:

> getParameterValues
>
> **java.lang.String[] getParameterValues(java.lang.String name)**
>
> **Returns an array of String objects containing all of the values the given
>   request parameter has**, or null if the parameter does not exist. If the
>   parameter has a single value, the array has a length of 1.
>
> Parameters: name - a String containing the name of the parameter whose
>   value is requested Returns: an array of String objects containing the
>   parameter's values See Also: getParameter(java.lang.String)

The method getParameterValue(String name) is provided as a convenience:

> getParameter
>
> **java.lang.String getParameter(java.lang.String name)**
>
> Returns the value
>   of a request parameter as a String, or null if the parameter does not
>   exist. Request parameters are extra information sent with the request.
>   For HTTP servlets, parameters are contained in the query string or
>   posted form data. **You should only use this method when you are sure
>   the parameter has only one value. If the parameter might have more
>   than one value**, use getParameterValues(java.lang.String).
>
> **If you use this method with a multivalued parameter, the value
>   returned is equal to the first value in the array returned by
>   getParameterValues.**

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer Alan. I am able to understand this behavior from the aspect of getParameterValue() method. Also, I would like to ask If there is any rule from the perspective of type of request like POST values override the GET values in some cases or vice-versa ?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. While your server may process them in a consistent manner, basing logic on on any observed behaviour would be dangerous.

Answer (score -1):

Because getParameter() in this case is grabbing it from your GET, not your POST.

See, your action is explicitly specifying the username to be uname1, and then your POST says uname2, I'm not really sure how java decides which parameter to accept, off the top of my head, but you can just remove the query trying parameter of your post form and it should work fine.

Answer (score -1):

By default http uses GET method, here you are mentioning explicitly username in the action and trying to send them using POST. I think http is sending that data through GET method rather than POST.